# With a Flex ColumnChart, is there a way to center the datatip over the column

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, flex-charting

I'm using a Flex ColumnChart with a custom *dataTipRenderer*.  I'm able to apply a nice skin with the dataTipRenderer, but am not sure how to move the datatip to be centered.

Is there a way to have the chart center the data tips over the column instead of the normal top-right alignment the chart does?

Instead of:

```
      |tip text|
    +++
    +++
    +++
    +++
    +++
    +++
    +++
    +++
```

I want:

```
| tip text |
    +++
    +++
    +++
    +++
    +++
    +++
    +++
    +++
```

Any ideas involving HitData, etc, would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a dataTipRenderer you can set the property x in the main component (canvas, hbox or vbox) like this:
x="this.x - (this.width* .5)"

Comment: That just sort of shifts the same issue to the left a bit.  It's right more of the time, but doesn't work at the right edge.

Comment: i'm not really sure what you want. But the way i'm doing it you can place the dataTip everywhere you want. y property you can set the y position. It is as simple as that.

Comment: My bad I see what you mean now. I tested my code on a linechart but on a bar chart it's refusing to work

Comment: Your solution works if the chart's container has enough room on the right side for the tip to be displayed.  I didn't leave enough padding in the canvas.  Pretty simple.